# Swift 3.0 CIEdgeWork filter not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cifilter, ciimage

I am trying to apply CIEdgeWork filter to my inputImage and place the filtered image into myImage (which is a UIImageView).  I'm not getting any result (just a blank screen).  This same style code works with other filters like CIEdges.  Anyone know what i'm doing wrong?  Testing on ios10 devices.

```
let context = CIContext(options: nil)

if let edgeWorkFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIEdgeWork") {
  let beginImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
  edgeWorkFilter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
  edgeWorkFilter.setValue(3.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

  if let output = edgeWorkFilter.outputImage {
    if let cgimg = context.createCGImage(output, from: output.extent) {
      let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg)
      myImage.image = processedImage
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, can we change edge color?? 
Current is white for me but I need a black color edge...

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution, set background color of the image to something other than White.

Comment: Which image? i tried setting UIImageView background to gray but still same problem.

Comment: @Avvan self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray